# Trying to run jquery event on window resize not working?

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, load

I currently have a function adding/removing a class once the user scrolls down a certain part of the page. The page is dependent on the user's screen size and currently it only works the first time the page is loaded after that the scroll function won't match the scroll if the user resizes the window.

This is what I have currently, am I missing something?

```
$(function() {
   var header = $(".logo").addClass('lightLogo');
   var about = $(".angle").offset().top;;
   $(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= about) {
        header.removeClass('lightLogo').addClass('darkLogo');
    } else {
        header.removeClass('darkLogo').addClass('lightLogo');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra ';' on the end of the line below

```
var about = $(".angle").offset().top;;
```

Works if you remove it.

Comment: Great, didn't see that. Also is there a way to make the function actually add/remove on the angle. Currently I've created a css transform so it looks like there is a slant on the page, but when it hits that div it acts a horizontal line and doesn't actually change on the angle? Any ideas?

Comment: Not to sure what you mean, maybe if you put the relevant code in a jsFiddle I could have a look